# How to assign html table to Variable

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

> I need this table to one variable, so that I can pass this variable as
>   String to my email program.
>
> message.setContent(variable, "text/html");
>
> I need this variable as Webemails not supporting scripting executions
>   at their front
>
> Is there any way I can pull table information to variable?? is it
>   possible??

I'm using angular js and displaying table as

```
    <table>
        <tr>

            <th>UserId</th>
            <th>UserName</th>
            <th>Points</th>

        </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="country in countries.userpointsList| orderBy:'country.uservo.userId' ">

<td> {{ country.uservo.userId }}</td>
<td >{{ country.uservo.userName }}</td>  
<td> {{ country.points }}</td>
```

How I can put this table to one variable??

Comment: incomplete question.

Comment: It's surprising how some people are helpless, I posted here to get somehelp, simply click unvote doesnot help, anyway i found answer

Comment: [This has nothing to do with Java.](http://javascriptisnotjava.io/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply do `variable = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0]`. So the `variable` will contain the entire HTML code of the table

Answer (score 0):

```
it works

<html>



<body>

<div id="sasi" >
<table border="1">
<tr><td>sasikar</td><td>sasikar</td></tr>
<tr><td>srikar</td> <td>sasikar</td></tr>
</table>
<script>
var k="";

k=document.getElementById("sasi").innerHTML;
alert(k);
</script>
</html>
```